# Translating Unicode to Latin in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, collation

In SQL Server you can convert Unicode character sets into Latin character sets by using

```
CAST(src COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2 AS VARCHAR(255))
```

However the collate function does not exist in Teradata, I know you can use collation to set the session character display, but how would I translate the character `č` -> `c`?

Comment: As `č` is not a character of the Latin char set afaik there's no way to translate it to `c`

Comment: In fact, it is part of Latin charset: ISO/IEC 8859-2 aka Latin-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `TRANSLATE (<your column> using UNICODE_TO_LATIN)`. I don't think all unicode characters will be able to be converted to latin though.

Comment: You are correct it will not translate. Teradata throws a untranslatable string error.